# How to disable proxy setting in phantomjs?

Tags: proxy, phantomjs

I can [set proxy](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/openurlwithproxy.js#L12) in script:

```
phantom.setProxy('192.168.1.42', 8080, 'http', 'user', 'passwd');
```

But how can I disable previous proxy in script without restarting `phantomjs`.

I want to write a phantomjs rendering service which accept a `proxy` argument (optional) for every request.

Comment: Interesting, this function is not even documented here: http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/ There is no other proxy function, see https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/src/phantom.h

Comment: What happens if you call `phantom.setProxy('');`? Will it reset properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only just recently discovered `setProxy()` and have been experimenting with it, so I'd share that yes, doing

```
phantom.setProxy("");
```

does reset proxy in PhantomJS, even after some pages have been opened.